# How can i split 2 objects in a array Mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I use `mongoose.find()` to list all of my data. I try to push the data in a array but all of my data is just in a array like:

```
const find = Info.find({}).then((data)=>  
{                                          
    posts.push(data);

    console.log(posts[0])
})

})
```

but the output is:

```
{ 

    id: randomthing,
    name: randomthing,
                                                      
}, 

{ 

    id: randomthing2,
    name:randomthing2, 

}
```

> I want just the first object when I log posts[0]  how can I split them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data` is an array. If you push it into `posts` and then read it again, it will always be an array.

Change `posts.push(data);` to `posts.push(...data);` to push the whole array into `posts`